# a query to show name of the bus and busno, where source of a bus is the destination of another bus and vice versa

Tags: sql, rdbms

There are two tables, one is **Buses**, where the bus names and bus no.s will be available and another is **schedule** , where the bus no.s, sources of the buses and destinations of the buses will be available. So basically, here we need to display the name and no of two buses as the final output, where bus X has the destination of bus Y as its source and bus Y has the source of bus X as its destination. Since the source and destination are in the same table, I don't know how to form the logic. And the concept essentially to be used for this problem is Joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code similar to this should do the trick:

```
SELECT buses.name, buses.number
FROM buses JOIN (SELECT sc1.number
                 FROM schedule AS sc1 JOIN schedule AS sc2
                 ON sc1.source = sc2.destination 
                 AND sc1.destination = sc2.source) AS s1
ON buses.number = s1.number
```

Not sure exactly which SQL you are writing with as far as syntax but this should be logically correct.

Comment: You're missing the `ON` condition for the first `JOIN`

Comment: Can you suggest me some sources, from where I can learn more of Sub-queries and Joins?

Comment: Really good tutorial that taught me almost everything I know about SQL, the topics are on the left side including subequeries and joins: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it without sub-query

```
select b.bus_no, b.bus_name
from buses b, schedule s1, schedule s2
where b.bus_no=s1.bus_no and s1.source=s2.destination
and s2.source=s1.destination and s1.bus_no!=s2.bus_no
order by 1;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
select b.bus_no, b.bus_name,s1.source,s1.destination
from buses b, schedule s1, schedule s2
where b.bus_no=s1.bus_no and s1.source=s2.destination
and s2.source=s1.destination and s1.bus_no!=s2.bus_no
order by bus_no;
```

Comment: This will do your job

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'as' and the result will come.

```
   select buses.bus_no,buses.bus_name
    from buses join( select sc1.bus_no
                    from  schedule sc1 join schedule sc2
                    on  sc1.source=sc2.destination
                    and sc1.destination=sc2.source )  s1
                    on buses.bus_no=s1.bus_no ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.BUS_NO,BUS_NAME FROM BUSES B JOIN (SELECT S.BUS_NO FROM SCHEDULE S JOIN SCHEDULE S1 ON S.SOURCE=S1.DESTINATION 
AND S.DESTINATION=S1.SOURCE) TMP 
ON B.BUS_NO=TMP.BUS_NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select bus_no,bus_name from buses 
where bus_no in(select sc1.bus_no from schedule sc1,schedule sc2 
where sc1.source=sc2.destination and sc1.destination=sc2.source) 
order by bus_no;`

Here I have used self join concept in subquery as:
"**select sc1.bus_no from schedule sc1,schedule sc2 
where sc1.source=sc2.destination and sc1.destination=sc2.source**".
This sub-query will return all the bus_no from schedule table whose source is same as destination and finally main query will return corresponding bus_no and bus_name from bus table whose bus_no matches to the list of bus_no returned by sub-query.

Comment: order by is not necessary here

Comment: Add an explanation.

Comment: @GrantMiller I have added the explanation as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it **without joins**:

```
select bus_no,bus_name from buses where bus_no in (
    select s1.bus_no from schedule s1,schedule s2 
    where s1.source=s2.destination and s1.destination=s2.source
)
order by bus_no;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Understanding and works 100%**

select distinct buses.bus_no, buses.bus_name from buses
where buses.bus_no in(select s1.bus_no from schedule s1 join schedule s2 on s1.source=s2.destination and s2.source = s1.destination)
order by buses.bus_no;

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.